# TFS 2010 API: Queue builds synchronously and get the state of each queued build: "Run On Agent (waiting for build agent)"

Tags: c#, tfs, build-agent

Is it possible to queue builds synchronously?

I tried something like this:

**CodeActivity:**

```
[BuildActivity(HostEnvironmentOption.Agent)]
public sealed class QueueNewBuild : CodeActivity<BuildResult>
{
    // The Team Project that the build definition belongs to.
    [RequiredArgument]
    public InArgument<IBuildDetail> BuildDetail { get; set; }

    // The build definition to queue
    [RequiredArgument]
    public InArgument<String> BuildDefinition { get; set; }

    protected override BuildResult Execute(CodeActivityContext context)
    {
        // Obtain the runtime value of the input arguments
        var buildDefinitionName = context.GetValue(BuildDefinition);
        var buildDetail = context.GetValue(BuildDetail);

        // Obtain the Team Project for the current build definition.
        var tfsProject = buildDetail.BuildDefinition.TeamProject;

        var configurationServerUri = buildDetail.BuildServer.TeamProjectCollection.Uri.ToString();

        var server = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(new Uri(configurationServerUri));
        server.EnsureAuthenticated();
        var buildServer = server.GetService<IBuildServer>();
        var buildDefinition = buildServer.GetBuildDefinition(tfsProject, buildDefinitionName);

        var queuedBuild = buildServer.QueueBuild(buildDefinition);

        var buildStatusWatcher = new BuildStatusWatcher(queuedBuild.Id);
        buildStatusWatcher.Connect(buildServer, tfsProject);

        do
        {
        } while (buildStatusWatcher.Status != QueueStatus.Completed && buildStatusWatcher.Status != QueueStatus.Canceled);

        buildStatusWatcher.Disconnect();

        return new BuildResult
        {
            WasSuccessfully = buildStatusWatcher.Build.CompilationStatus == BuildPhaseStatus.Succeeded, 
            BuildDetail = buildStatusWatcher.Build
        };
    }
}
```

**BuildResult:**

```
public class BuildResult
{
    public bool WasSuccessfully { get; set; }
    public IBuildDetail BuildDetail { get; set; }
}
```

**BuildStatusWatcher:**

```
public class BuildStatusWatcher
{
    private IQueuedBuildsView _queuedBuildsView;
    private readonly int _queueBuildId;
    private QueueStatus _status;
    private IBuildDetail _build;

    public BuildStatusWatcher(int queueBuildId)
    {
        _queueBuildId = queueBuildId;
    }

    public IBuildDetail Build
    {
        get { return _build; }
    }

    public QueueStatus Status
    {
        get { return _status; }
    }

    public void Connect(IBuildServer buildServer, string tfsProject)
    {
        _queuedBuildsView = buildServer.CreateQueuedBuildsView(tfsProject);
        _queuedBuildsView.StatusChanged += QueuedBuildsViewStatusChanged;
        _queuedBuildsView.Connect(10000, null);
    }

    public void Disconnect()
    {
        _queuedBuildsView.Disconnect();
    }

    private void QueuedBuildsViewStatusChanged(object sender, StatusChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Changed)
        {
            var queuedBuild = _queuedBuildsView.QueuedBuilds.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == _queueBuildId);
            if (queuedBuild != null)
            {
                _status = queuedBuild.Status;
                _build = queuedBuild.Build;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So I am trying to wait as long as the build is completed or canceled, but this does not work, because the build agent of the sub build is waiting the whole time.

I have one master build process (runs on agent 1) which invokes 13 sub build process (all run on agent 2). And I want to wait for each sub build process so that I can abort the master build process when a sub build process fails.

Any ideas?

**UPDATE:**

> Service 'XXX - Agent1' had an exception:  Exception Message: The
>   operation did not complete within the allotted timeout of 00:00:30.
>   The time allotted to this operation may have been a portion of a
>   longer timeout. (type FaultException`1)
>
> Exception Stack Trace:    at
>   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Machine.BuildAgentService.TerminateWorkflow(TerminatingException
>   ex)

**The workflow:**

[image]

Comment: So, you are saying that ALL your programmatically requested Build fail to start? Or that you can't order multiple Builds?

Comment: It hangs at the first queued sub build. "Run On Agent (waiting for build agent). The build agent for the sub build has the state: "Executing workflow". The build agent state for the main build is: "Ready"

Comment: I figured out, that  the agent does not hang everytime. The build agent "hangs" sporadic.

Answer (score 1):

Since all you have is one additional Build Agent, I think it doesn't bring you much to employ such a complex module.
I would implement two separate Activities:
One Activity that takes as input a `BuildDetail` and a `BuildDefinition` as exits once a new build has been queued.
I would invoke this activity within a loop in the XAML. This would queue all builds in build agent #2. 
The second activity would check on the Status of build agent #2 & wait the agent to become idle again.
Once it does so, I would check for each build definition that is supposed to have ran successfully in Agent #2 with something like that:
`if(buildDefinition.LastGoodBuildUri != buildDefinition.LastBuildUri)`
What might seem as a disadvantage with this approach, is fact that build will NOT fail/stop at the very first breaking "child" builds.
In my opinion, that is actually an advantage: If more than one fails, you 'll know immediately.

Comment: I did find the issue. The wrong build agent is choosen by the my master build. But I dont know why this is the case, because I set up the master build definition to use a specific Agent.

Answer (score 1):

I created a special template for kicking off builds in order. The basic template:

**Get the build, QueueBuild, MonitorBuild**

**Get the Build** is the activity that is in the default template. It is the first activity in my template and only called once in the beginning.

**QueueBuild** is the activity gotten from TFSExtensions at codeplex. I create a variable that holds an IQueueBuild object which is the Result of the QueueBuild activity for each build I plan to kick off. I set the Result to this variable. I called mine CurrentQueueBuild. After every QueueBuild activity kicks off a build, this variable gets updated to the current build queue by the activity.

**MonitorBuild** is a sequence that I made that does most of the 'syncing':

First is an activity that checks if CurrentQueueBuild is null (CurrentQueueBuild Is Nothing). If it is I throw an exception as I can't have that.

Second is a While activity (called 'While building'). Its condition is 'CurrentQueueBuild.Status = BuildStatus.InProgress'. In the body of the the While I have another sequence that contains an InvokeMethod activity (TargetObject = CurrentQueueBuild, MethodName = Refresh and I added In parameter of type QueryOptions set to QueryOptions.All). I follow the InvokeMethod with a delay activity set to wait 5 seconds.

Finally I write a build message to log the status. This obviously is optional.

So to wrap up, I have 5 builds I kick off and for each one I have a **QueueBuild** activity followed by a **Monitor Build** activity put together as described above.

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: How is this NOT the accepted answer? This was a very simple solution to what could be a nasty problem.